# Anaconda-navigator no se abre

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, linux-mint

estaba trabajando normalmente con anaconda-navigator en linux-mint y de golpe el so crasheó, reinicié el pc y de golpe me sale este error al introducir 'anaconda-navigator' en la consola:

```
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 99, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/logs.py", line 18, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config import (LOG_FILENAME, LOG_FOLDER,
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/main.py", line 90, in <module>
    raw_mode=True,
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 279, in load_from_ini
    self.read(self.filename(), encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1014, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tuve ese problema cuando trabajaba con anaconda en Debian, la única solución que encontré fue reinstalarlo desde el terminal. El problema es causado por una cadena de bits que python intenta pasar a utf-8, y en el intento aparece alguna secuencia que no reconoce con utf-8.
Podrías abrir el archivo que contiene el error y solucionarlo leyendolo caracter por caracter para encontrar el error con python, o abrirlo entero de la siguiente manera:

```py
with open(ruta, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
```

O en un for para averiguar cual es.
No entiendo bien la causa por la que se corrompen los archivos pero como te digo mi solución fue reinstalarlo al completo. Siento no poderte ayudar mejor.